# C# Windows Forms - Access to path ... Denied

Tags: c#, winforms

-- SOLVED BY --
**adding Thread.Sleep(2000) before deleting the file.

Thanks to Ivan.**

---

Hi guys, it seems that this question has a related questions but I think my problem is different.. and it's very odd.

My problem is, am trying to Delete a file.. an PNG file.. but everytime the FileInfo.Delete() is called, I get this **Access to path, denied** error. I checked the permission and everything is enabled, Read-only - nope. I even add **Everyone** user but I still get the same error. I read somewhere that if I have some files (except the executable files, dll, etc) .. I must not put in "Program Files" or anywhere I think is not safe.. So I decided to put it in "My Documents" but it's so odd that I still get the same error?

What's wrong with this?

and about the code, well let's just say something like this

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\JWMD Themer\\Start_Icon_SettingsS.png");
fi.Delete();

// or alternatively, I can just use

Path.Copy([srcFile], [destFile]);
```

Comment: Your Windows version and the account running your application might be highly relevant.

Comment: Is it possible the file is being held open by your application preventing it from being deleted?

Comment: Am using "Administrator" account.

Comment: @Bubbafat - I tried looking for that in my code, back and forth, 2, 3x am sure this file is not being used by my application neither other applications :(

Comment: Could you test the following: run your application and make it somehow pause before deleting (if nothing else, some long Thread.Sleep, or remove code for deleting). Then try deleting in Windows. It shouldn't work. So, or your application is using it or it is used somewhere else.

Comment: It seems this file might be opened; it's handle is held by some application.
Did you save this file in "My documents" programatically?

Comment: Did you try solution from Suraj? It seens to be true

Comment: Are you running this code inside a Windows Service?

Comment: @ukhardy - the app was Themer for Windows Mobile, so most likely, users would put the theme folder with files (images, etc) everywhere. but for the Themer rule.. it must be in "My Documents"

Comment: Just a thought. Did you try deleting the file directly in explorer to make sure you can do it there? Just to rule out the code as the source of the problem.

Comment: @Anton - as what I said to Suraj, the code above was just a sample code, even the path.. the original code was .. there are some path and file validations first before deleting or copying. The code at the end will look just like this: FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(bkFile); fi.Delete();

Comment: @JohnFx - yes! I did that! and it worked well.

Comment: I'll have to reboot my system.. and let's see what will happen..

Comment: Are you using the fileInfo object for anything but the delete? Maybe you could try just System.IO.File.Delete(filePath) and not create a separate object. It didn't do it in my quick test, but maybe that object is holding a reference that is locking the file?

Comment: @Ivan - I put a breakpoint on Delete() and paused for about 3 seconds or so, and it successfully deleted the file!! what's the explanation on that??

Comment: The code throws this exception even if the file to be modified is read-only. Wasted my half an hour's time..

Answer (score 2):

try 
add "@" before c:   like(@"c:\windows....")

Comment: the code above is just a sample.. so It's just a sample path.. the original code was like this string srcFilename = Path.GetFileName(lblNewImagePath.Text);
            string destFilepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(this.datafile), srcFilename);

Answer (score 1):

You could use  [Unlocker](http://unlocker.emptyloop.com/) to verify, that it is not an issue with an open file handle.

Comment: hey yeah Unlocker. Let me try that and get back here

Comment: Am using Windows 7 and Unlocker did not found any even if the my app is running..

Comment: Than that's not your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Being logged as administrator or running application as administrator doesn't give you rights to delete any file you want in NTFS filesystem. Check if administrator have permission to write on this file - if not you will have change owner of file to admin and gave him permission.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to delete in Windows Explorer under the same circumstances, I believe solution should be to use [Windows Shell API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio as administrator.

I don't know what more difference does it make except than giving you privileges, but i solved this with this.